# "Inverse" of graph colouring problem

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory

From my (limited) understanding, in colouring problems in graph theory one is interested in finding all graphs for which there exists some colouring satisfying certain conditions. I am interested in the inverse problem somehow:

> Given a specific class of graphs, let's say that we have defined an
>   inductive way to colour the vertices of a graph in this class. Let's say that such a graph is *acceptable* if, after we colour its vertices in this inductive way, certain properties are satisfied. Can we find all acceptable graphs?

Note that the inductive way that we define doesn't have to give a unique colour to each vertex a priori, so for example one could say that a graph is acceptable if every vertex has a unique colour. Or maybe one could be interested in whether the inductive way gives us a proper colouring of the graph.

My question is: is this problem studied? If yes, are there any references? And if no, can it be translated to a usual colouring problem somehow?

Comment: Question seems very vague and abstract to me. Can you give an example or two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From one point of view, a $\lambda$-colouring on a graph is just a partition of its vertex set into $\lambda$ independent sets. And then of course we can generalise this to arbitrary properties - "is there/find a partition $P$ of $V_{G}$ such that for all $u_{1},...,u_{n}$ in some $p \in P$, such and such" e.g. colour the graph so that for all $u,v$, they have the same colour iff they are adjacent [the opposite of usual colourings, results in a partition into connected components].

In this sense, I'm sure that a few alternative versions of colourings/labelings have been looked into - [graceful labelings](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graceful_labeling) for example.

Outside graphs but still in combinatorics, there is Ramsey theory, whose whole focus is precisely partitions avoiding/preserving arbitrary properties. In Ramsey theory one asks, for instance, "can we colour the integers from $1$ to $n$ so that no $x,y,z$ of the same colour class form a Pythagorean triple?" [for all $n > 8000$ the answer is no]. In Ramsey theory though, one usually is interested in the least such $n$ [such that every $\lambda$-colouring of $[n]$ has a monochromatic subset with a given property].

Now I'm not quite sure what you mean by "inductive way of colouring". If you have a colouring algorithm then it can be studied on its own right. E.g. greedy algorithms for graph colouring always colour properly, but are not always able to do so even when the given graph is colourable.